# regular expression to find all substrings inside double quotes php

Tags: php, regex, double-quotes, substring

I have a big database that has fields of paragraphs that are formatted like this:

["This is the first sentence", "This is the second sentent", "This is the third sentence", "This is the fourth sentence"]

I would like to extract the (using PHP) and put them in an array where each array element is a sentence. Right now, I am using this:

```
$trim_joined = substr($joined, 2, -2); //gets rid of the first and last bracket and double quote
$sentences = explode('", "', $trim_joined);
```

It seems a bit fragile because I am not 100% sure that this field follows this exact same format for every row of the database (over 350,000 rows). I was wondering if there is a regular expression that extracts ALL elements of the strings that are inside double quotes and puts them in an array. This way, I don't have to worry if there are entries without the brackets at beginning and end.

Unfortunately, i now little to nothing about regex so asking for help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You could do `eval()` on the entire thing, but no guarantee that that couldn't be used against you by a malicious user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format was consistent you could just use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) - as the rows are pretty much lists of strings. I would totally test that first, even if it runs a few minutes.

Failing that you can use a somewhat more robust [`CSV`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) parser, after simply [`trim`](http://php.net/trim)ing the square brackets (I would conjecture that's the optimum approach here):

```
 $strings = str_getcsv(trim(trim($row, "["), "]"));
```

The simplest regex solution would be:

```
 preg_match_all('/"([^"]*)"\K/', $row, $strings);
```

Comment: these work too...i might use them because i am still not sure all the entries follow the exact same structure yet and these trims can't hurt if they don't match

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way without regex:

You could use `json_decode()`:

```
<?php
$data='["This is the first sentence", "This is the second sentent", "This is the third sentence", "This is the fourth sentence"]';
$arr=json_decode($data,true);
print_r($arr);
?>
```